# How to type annotate length of string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to type annotate a function that only accepts a single character in python, take this example:
`(s: str) -> int`

As Python doesn't have a type for a single char, you can't just do something like `(s: char) -> int`.

***Is there any way to type that the `s: str` should only be one character?***

I could see this being useful in hinting when writing code.

Here's my full example:

```py
import unicodedata

roman_numeral_lookup = {"I": 1, "V": 5, "X": 10, ...}

def exact_roman_numeral(s: str) -> int:
    """Return the value of a single Roman numeral. Dosen't support multicharacter roman numerals such as 'XII' or Apostrophus."""

    # Convert Unicode Roman numerals into to their normalised text version. e.g. Ⅹ -> X, ⅰ -> I
    s = unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", s).upper()

    if s in roman_numeral_lookup:
        return roman_numeral_lookup[s]

    else:  # Some form of invalid value.
        if not isinstance(s, str):
            raise TypeError("Argument must be of type str.")
        elif len(s) != 1:
            raise ValueError("Must be a single Roman numeral.")
        else:
            raise ValueError("Not a valid/supported Roman numeral.")
```

(I know the errors aren't the best)

Comment: [Doesn't seem like it's going to be built-in](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4334), but since python types are purely semantic anyway you can probably just make your own.

Comment: Since the lenght of string is not a part of it's type, this is not really possible. Even if you synacticly describe it, I don't think you can typecheck it at compile time.

Comment: There isn't. More on typing in Python here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/ and here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/ (abridged)

Comment: People expect way too much out of type annotations. Not every constraint in your program can or should be expressed with a type annotation.

Comment: Python 3+ strings are unicode by default and length of a unicode string is potentially ambiguous in some cases

Comment: @user2357112-supports-monica As far as I understand typing is for hinting to devs and type checkers what the arguments and return values of a function should be.
Would typing for the length of a string not fit with this?

Comment: @IainShelvington Couldn't it just use the same method of calculating length as `len()` does?

Comment: @GoodClover Why don't you just create a simple class Char and use it for type hinting ?

Comment: @GoodClover The lenght of the string has nothing to do with it's type, this is not how `str` works. It is an attribute of the `str` object, which needs to be validated at runtime. And if you really want to validate it at compile time, you will end up with a type system like Rust's. I am not saying that it is a bad or wrong design, but while it allows you to describe what you want it also has so much restrictions you have to obey. Python is not this kind of language, just do your check at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in theory type-annotations shouldn't be used like you want them to - meaning, not every constraint in your code should be expressed by a type-annotation.

Now, to answer your question, you can, of course, build your own type-annotation but that would be, IMO, too much work for too less outcome.

There are [other answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=custom+python+type+annotation) which describe how a custom annotation can be defined

You can, at any point:

- describe in your docstring that your variable is supposed to be 1-char long
- do a sanity/validation check and raise a proper exception.
- use something like [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to sanitize/serialize your data

Comment: I don't see annotating the length of a string as too much different to annotating what the subtypes of a tuple/list (`tuple[int, int, str]`).
It's clear that at present there is no way to do it without a custom type, but something like `str[3]` seems simple enough to me.

How is something like this not how type anotations are meant to be used?

Comment: @GoodClover Const generics and type generics are different things, what you want is not as simple as it sounds. And you can't parameterize `str` because it is not a generic container.

Answer (score 1):

Natively, no.  Annotations can't do what you're asking.  But...

You could create a new type that upholds your rules of string length, etc and then use that type in your annotation.

```py
class MyStringThatShouldOnlyBeOneCharacter:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        # put your value checking here
        return

def exact_roman_numeral(s: MyStringThatShouldOnlyBeOneCharacter) -> int:
    ...
```